# Java: Couldn't comprehend type erasure on a non-static method

Tags: java, generics

This question has to do with type erasure and its implication on arrays [SCJP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Certified_Professional) (by Mughal - 3rd edition on page 726). Here's the code in short:

```
public class MyStack<E> implements IStack<E> {
    // Top of stack.
    private Node<E> tos;
    // Size of stack
    private int numOfElements;

    :

    // Incorrect version
    public E[] toArray3() {
        E[] toArray = (E[])new Object[numOfElements];
        int i=0;
        for (E data : this) {
           toArray[i++] = data;
        }
        return toArray;
    }

    // Correct version
    public E[] toArray4(E[] toArray) {
        if (toArray.length != numOfElements) {
            toArray = E[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(toArray.getClass().getComponentType(), numOfElements);
        }
        int i=0;
        for (E data : this) {
             toArray[i++] = data;
        }
        return toArray;
    }
}
```

According to the book, method `toArray3` is the incorrect version to use while method `toArray4` is the correct version since array is of [reifiable type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_%28computer_science%29). I don't have problem on this. However, I have a problem when it comes to understanding why type parameter `E` is different for `toArray3` and `toArray4`.

Here's how I found out. Supposedy I have the following:

```
MyStack<Integer> intStack = new MyStack<Integer>();
intStack.push(9);
Integer[] x = intStack.toArray4(new Integer[0]); // clause 1
System.out.println(x.length);
Integer[] y = intStack.toArray4(new Object[0]); // clause 2  - compiler error
System.out.println(y.length);
Integer[] z = intStack.toArray3(); // clause 3
System.out.println(z.length);
```

a. For clause 1, no problem. The type parameter E in toArray4 seems to be of Integer.

b. For clause 2, the error is saying that `Integer[]` is not applicable for `Object[]`. Does that mean that type erasure of `toArray4(E[] toArray)` is `toArray4[Integer[] toArray)`? Why not Object[]? (Though I know that `intStack` has been instiantiated with Integer.)

c. For clause 3, the runtime error is that saying `Object[]` cannot be assigned to `Integer[]`. I do understand this, but why now is the type parameter `E` on `toArray3` `Object` and not `Integer`?

*I would expect the type parameter E ON toArray3 to be the same as toArray4 since type parameter E itself for intStack is of integer type which are used by both toArray3 AND toArray4.*

Please bear in mind that in the body of `toArray3`, the array Object has been cast back to `E[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between these methods is that `toArray4()` is using reflection to obtain the `Class` object that represents the correct component type of the array.  This ensures that the type information is known at runtime in spite of type erasure.

The key is this line of `toArray4()`:

```
Array.newInstance(toArray.getClass().getComponentType(), numOfElements);
```

Unlike generic objects, arrays *can* provide their component type, since something like `Integer[]` has a corresponding `Class` object that can be inspected for this information.

Because of this, `toArray4()` actually instantiates an `Integer[]` object when `E` is `Integer`, whereas `toArray3()` instantiates an `Object[]` and the calling code (through type erasure) attempts to cast it to `Integer[]`, rightly causing a `ClassCastException`.

In general, reflection is often used as a workaround to type erasure.

As a note, arrays in Java tend to have certain "magic" associated with them, especially with regard to reflection. For example if you look at the source for `Class#getComponentType()` and `Array.newInstance()` they both lead to native code.

**EDIT:** I think the source of your confusion is the cast being done in `toArray3()`:

```
E[] toArray = (E[])new Object[numOfElements];
```

This is *not* the cast that is causing your `ClassCastException`. Rather it's a second cast which is added by type erasure. To illustrate, let's rewrite `toArray3()` as if type erasure had been applied:

```
public Object[] toArray3() {  
   Object[] toArray = new Object[numOfElements]; //first cast no longer necessary
   int i=0;  
   for (Object data : this) {  //pretend MyStack is no longer generic
      toArray[i++] = data;  
   }  
   return toArray;  
}
```

Then in the calling code:

```
Integer[] z = (Integer[])intStack.toArray3(); //ClassCastException
```

As you can see, the `ClassCastException` is thrown not in the method, but when its result is assigned to `z` using a cast, which type erasure creates for you.  We might verify this if you actually post the stacktrace.

Comment: toArray4 then has type parameter E as Integer. toArray3 created Object[] but being cast to E. I would expect E to be Integer too since E is same for both method. But it seems in toArray3 the Object[] is cast back to Object[] - which rightly produce the error later on. But the problem is why being cast back to Object[] and not Integer[] since E is an instance field which is used by both methods. Basically intStack has E as Integer. toArray4 rightly shows that while toArray3 not - since Object[] is being cast back to Object[] and not Integer[]

Comment: Where is it being cast back to `Object[]`? I'm not following you at all.

Comment: Because at clause 3, it gives a runtime error. It's returning Object[] and assigning to Integer[] - which produces runtime error as shown here "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;
 at IClient.main(IClient.java:17)" This shows toArray3 is returning Object[]. So it also shows that the cast (E[]) in this method is (Object[]) and not (Integer[])

Comment: Based on your edit, my source of confusion is why E is now Object in toArray3 while toArray4 shows E is Integer?

Comment: @yapkm01 `toArray4` actually shows `Object` and `Object[]` as a result type. It's just that arrays are covariant.

Comment: @yapkm01 - `E` has no meaning at runtime - that's what type erasure does, is change all `E` to `Object` and cast where necessary. The reason the type of the returned array is different between the methods during your program's execution is that the first method *doesn't work* - it causes a `ClassCastException` because an `Object[]` is not an `Integer[]`.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. So in toArray4, the actual array is integer but then it got cast to Object. Then why on clause 1 there is no error since the return Object[] (eventhough it is actually Integer[]) is assigned to Integer[]? If you now look at clause 2 where the Object[] is passed into the method, you get error now since it says only Integer[] can be used (since intStack has Integer instance field now)

Comment: Essentially my confusion is this. a) clause 1 no error - so far so good. b) clause 2 error - you cant passed Object[] into toArray4 since intStack has Integer instance field type. YOu can passe Integer[] tho'. c) Then this Integer field type should also apply to toArray3. IF that is the case then clause 3 will not fail since toArray3 will return Integer[]

Comment: @yapkm01 - To answer your first question: as alf said, arrays are covariant. This means `Integer[]` is a `Object[]` in the same way `Integer` is an `Object`. So the cast that type erasure does behind the scenes is valid. But as you say, in this case the array actually is of type `Integer[]` - if it gets declared as `Object[]` and then cast back to `Integer[]`, then fine. (continued)

Comment: @yapkm01 - (continued) In the case of clause 2, you're trying to pass in a plain `Object[]`. The compiler knows its cast back to `Integer[]` at the end would fail - an `Object[]` is *not* an `Integer[]`, so it gives you a compile error.

Comment: @yapkm01 - clause 3 results in a runtime error instead of a compile time error, because `toArray3()` is essentially lying to the compiler by casting `Object[]` to `E[]`.

Comment: Understood. Clause 2 succeed when you pass Integer[] and not Object[]. This means toArray4 on clause 2 has E as Integer. My point is shouldn't then E as Integer be applied to toArray3? If yes then toArray3 will be returning Integer[] and clause 3 will not have runtime error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4407/discussion-between-kublai-khan-and-yapkm01)

Comment: @Kublai - if you are free .. can u buzz me?

Comment: @Kublai - I still don't quite get it when  you said in toArray3() the cast (E[]) new Object[numOfElements] lied to the compiler. If i do understand you clearly from the discussion i have with you regarding toArray4 on the casting, why then in toArray3 the (E[]) new Object[numOfElements] is not cast to Integer since E is Integer? Meaning something like (Integer[])new Object[numOfElements] since intStack has Integer as instance field type

Comment: @yapkm01 - Casting is not the same as converting. If I have an `Object[]` instance there's no way I can get an `Integer[]` from it - this is where `toArray3()` is screwing up.  On the other hand if I have an actual `Integer[]` which is declared as `Object[]` then I can promise the compiler that it really is an `Integer[]` by casting it as such.

Comment: Conclusion: For both these methods, the post erasure for E is Object. This will be the type used during run time. In toArray4, since the array created is Integer the compiler produces an implicit cast back to Integer[] during the assignment stage. In the body of both methods, the cast to E[] is actually cast to Object[] during run time. However in toArray3 no implicit cast is produced since Object[] was actually created. One more note, in toArray4 you cannot passed an Object[] into it on the intStack object (Integer[] is ok) since that is a PRE ERASURE checking. Did i get all this right?

Comment: @yapkm01 - Exactly! :D And for your last question: yes, because `E` is being inferred as `Integer` based on the assignment. The following would be valid: `Object[] y = intStack.toArray4(new Object[0]);` because `E` is inferred to be `Object` in that case.

Comment: @Kublai - the statement Object[] y = intStack.toArray4(new Object[0]); doesn't work. Compiler error. I think because intStack has been instantiated with Integer, it must accept Integer[] or some subtype. Error is Integer[] in method toArray4 is not applicable to Object[] argument

Comment: @yapkm01 - Oh you're exactly right, I forgot about intStack. So if intStack was a `MyStack<Object>` in addition, then that statement would be valid.

Comment: Thank you. Been a tough subject

Comment: @yapkm01 - No problem, it was a good discussion about a relatively advanced topic.

Answer (score 2):

On **a**, no question here.

On **b**, type erasure happens *after* type validation. In compile-time, all the types are here.

On **c**, you explicitly create an array of `Object`, not `Integer`— no magic here.

The type parameter stays the same. It's just that you cannot cast `Object[]` to `Integer[]`.

Getting away from stacks, and narrowing your problem down:

```
public class MyStack<E> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] test = new MyStack<Integer>().test();
    }

    public E[] test() {
        return (E[]) (new Object[10]);
    }
}
```

Gives us the following bytecode:

```
Compiled from "MyStack.java"
public class org.acm.afilippov.stacko.MyStack extends java.lang.Object{
public org.acm.afilippov.stacko.MyStack();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   new #2; //class org/acm/afilippov/stacko/MyStack
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //Method "<init>":()V
   7:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method test:()[Ljava/lang/Object;
   10:  checkcast   #5; //class "[Ljava/lang/Integer;"
   13:  astore_1
   14:  return

public java.lang.Object[] test();
  Code:
   0:   bipush  10
   2:   anewarray   #6; //class java/lang/Object
   5:   checkcast   #7; //class "[Ljava/lang/Object;"
   8:   areturn

}
```

Note that in the `test()` method, generic types are erased — it's `new Object[]`, and `checkcast Object[]`.

In `main`, you assign to a non-generic variable, which means type cast; hence `checkcast    #5; //class "[Ljava/lang/Integer;"`

The trick which worries you in **b** is based on the fact that arrays are *covariant*, and the following is allowed:

```
Object[] array = new Integer[10];
```

So in case **b** the generic method has result type `Object[]`— but since you can assign `Integer[]` to `Object[]`, it's okay. See more at [Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ104).

Comment: For c, yes. But it has been cast back to Integer if you look at the method body of toArray3

Comment: The problem i have on toArray3 method is, what is type parameter E during runtime? Is it Object or Integer?. From the error, it shows that type parameter E is Object. Then why the type parameter E in toArray4 is Integer?

Comment: @alf - Agreed, you can no more cast an `Object[]` to type `Integer[]` than an `Object` to type `Integer`.

Comment: @Kublai Then why type parameter E in toArray4 seems to be Integer?

Comment: @yapkm01 so you were right on  "it has been cast back to Integer" and I was wrong. See above.

Comment: No. I would expect toArray3 to cast Object[] back to Integer[]. But it is not. It is cast back to Object[]. Hence the runtime error at clause 3 .. returning an Object[] and assigning it to Integer[]. I would expect toArray3 to return Integer[] and assigned back to Integer[] at clause 3 - producing no error.

Comment: See the bytecode above. The whole generics trickery means there's no `Integer` in `test()`— cast only happens when you assign to a non-generic variable.